# Data Entry form in VBA for research o

Tags: excel, vba

I am conducting a research project, and am trying to simplify my data entry process. While I could theoretically just enter the data directly into the sheet, I'm afraid I will end up in the wrong row and end up accidentally overwriting a previous entry, or just getting completely lost once I end up with a couple hundred rows. I would ideally like to make a form which will fill automatically to Excel rows. I would prefer to do this via software, but I haven't found anything great, and have come to the conclusion that I need to use VBA. This is a problem, as I haven't done any code other than a few weeks of HTML in computer camp when I was a kid. This is my first time venturing away from the basic user-facing processes in Excel (also why does VBA look exactly like Office 2003?)

I want to have a number of data entry styles (free entry, dropdown, radio buttons, and for the information from each subject to go into its own row. Ideally, I would also like to have some of the choices grey out the whole row (and exclude it from my data) if it fulfills my exclusion criteria. Within some of the choices, I would also ideally like to be able to enter a value, and have the next column over flag it as "abnormal" if it falls out of a preset range, but I can do both of these things manually if it is getting too complicated.

So far, my main takeaway from my research has been that VBA seems to be what I should use. I tried watching a few different videos on the topic, and am somewhat able to create a form. My one challenge here is that I can't seem to figure out how to add options to my dropdown lists. I'm trying to do this by going to "view" "code" and then entering

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
ComboBox1.AddItem([apples],[bananas])
End Sub
```

But I'm getting "Compile error: Expected =", so obviously I'm going wrong somewhere.

Also, I'm running out of room on my form, and don't see how to make more space (w/ a scroll bar) at the bottom (I can only make it as tall as my screen).

That said, the big problem here is obviously trying to figure out how on earth I get my data to send to the excel sheet itself so that I can analyze it. I don't even know where to start on this. The example code I see online seems quite different from what I'm trying to do (to my untrained eyes) - e.g.  the example at https://www.contextures.com/xlUserForm02.html

Does anyone have some code that is closer to what I'm attempting? I'll take any help I can get.

Edit: I found some code online that kind of seems to match what I'm trying to do (I still have to figure out the radio boxes, I may just use more dropdowns instead even if it is more clicks) but I'm getting "compile error:member already exists in an object module from which this object derives" I copied it from here as directed, and then edited it to match my fields, so I'm not sure what went wrong:

```
Private Sub problem()
    'Populate control.
    Me.cboClass.AddItem "Amphibian"
    Me.cboClass.AddItem "Bird"
    Me.cboClass.AddItem "Fish"
    Me.cboClass.AddItem "Mammal"
    Me.cboClass.AddItem "Reptile"

End Sub

Private Sub addcase()
    'Copy input values to sheet.
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    With ws
        .Cells(lRow, 1).Value = nmbr
        .Cells(lRow, 2).Value = problem
        .Cells(lRow, 3).Value = age
    End With

    'Clear input controls.
    patientnmbr = ""
    Chiefcomplaint = ""
    agebox = ""


End Sub

Private Sub cmdClose_Click()
    'Close UserForm.
    Unload Me

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't populate the combobox during the change event of itself, might end up with weird results...

Try to populate from other places (you would usually start with the userform initialization for some basic stuff), possible other events (button press, textbox change, other combobox change):

See if this helps:

```vb
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With ComboBox1
        .AddItem "one item"
        .AddItem "two items"
        .AddItem "three items"
        .AddItem "more items"
        .AddItem "how many items?!"
    End With
End Sub
```

The above helps with the specific problem you shown code for.

As for where to start and more details, I would make a search (any general search engine should do) for *VBA Userforms Data Entry*, there are some great and detailed tutorials out there to create from basic to more complex forms.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything in the dropdown when I add this. Where do I put it? Just as another instruction, unrelated to the automatically created "Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
End Sub" ?

Comment: You can add the above in the userform's code part, under your current `Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()` or above it... doesn't make any difference. If you click in any of the `Sub`s, at the top you should have some drop down selections, you can use those to see what other events you can use with any of the userforms controls (comboboxes, textboxes, etc) or even the userform itself (i.e.: the initialize event).

Comment: Thank you. I added a piece of code I got from a different website to my original post - would you be able to take a look?